# Returning Value Based On Row & Column Headings

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to get Excel to fill in a table with values based on the Headings of its Rows & Columns.  The source data is in a list in another table.

[image: Excel]

Basically I want to get the price of the products from TAB 2 into the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you first Tab is called Tab1 and second tab is called Tab2 and your tabs start at A1.

You can easily do this with INDEX-MATCH:

In tab1 B2 enter the following

```
INDEX($C$1:$C$8,MATCH($A2&B$1,'Tab2'!$A$1:$A$8&'Tab2'!$B$1:$B$8,0))
```

After entering this press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter it as array formula. Afterwards you can drag the formula to the rest of tab1.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, the last semicolon is preventing me from entering the formula

Comment: @Bahtfeng either use the comma or the semicolon, depending on your regional settings, not both. It's just a typo

Comment: No need to CSE - index is already an array formula.

Comment: @Raystafarian I tried not pressing CSE, but then I did not get the desired results.

Comment: Oh because you're concatenating, heh

Comment: Yes- AMAZING! It worked, thanks so much. 

I'm asuming the & is concatnating

Comment: @Raystafarian Now I am getting a #Ref error, the cells are all there so I'm not sure why this is the case

Comment: @Bahtfeng, did you change your tab names or the location of one of the cells? That could explain the #Ref error

Comment: @Michthan I've fixed it :) Wasn't a tab name issue, but I was missing a number in the range for the match - Silly mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Easier would be a [sumproduct](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) in B2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet2!$C$1:$C$8*(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$8=$A2)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$8=B$1))
```

Drag it across your entire table.